# In R, how can I found the ocurrence of n consecutive numbers in a character string

Tags: r, regex

I have a vector of characters with a fairly repeatable structure that I want to convert to a `data.frame`.
At the moment I'm marking the separation between columns adding a `\t`.
One of the fields is a number that at least has 5 characters so I'd like to find where it begins and ends to add a separation mark on both ends.

My vector resembles this one:

```
v_char <- c(
  "1 Name that may contain 2 number  1234567890 more content later",
  "2 Other name that doesn't have a number  1234567870 more content later"
)
```

I'd like to obtain this vector:

```
out_v_char <- c(
  "1 Name that may contain 2 number  \t1234567890\t more content later",
  "2 Other name that doesn't have a number  \t1234567870\t more content later"
)
```

I haven't been able to find a regex expression to mark the consecutive appearance of numbers and then find their begin and end.
I have reached the position of the blocks as follows but it seems like an overkill:

```
digits <- gregexpr("[0-9]", v_char)
f_tmp <- function(v) {
  cumsum(c(1L, diff(v) > 1))
}
blocks <- lapply(digits, f_tmp)
f_tmp2 <- function(v, n = 5L) {
  tb <- table(v)
  first_consecutive <- min(names(tb)[tb > n])
  return(c(start = head(which(
    v == first_consecutive
  ), 1L),
  end = tail(which(
    v == first_consecutive
  ), 1L)))
}
positions <- lapply(blocks, f_tmp2)
```

Comment: If you have multiple such occurrences in `v_char`, you can use `stringr::str_replace_all(v_char, "(\\d{5,})", "\t\\1\t")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can actually just use a simple `gsub` here

```
gsub("(\\d{5,})", "\t\\1\t", v_char)
```

This regular expression matches and captures a sequence of 5 or more ("{5,}") digits ("\d"). Then the `gsub` takes the captured match ("\1") and adds tabs before and after it before replacing the value in the string.

Comment: Thanks a lot exactly what I needed. I'll accept it when the minimum 10 minutes pass